# Event$ object was thrown resolving an image frame: [object Event]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-web-browser

======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following Event$ object was thrown resolving an image frame:
[object Event]

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vecteezy.com%2Ffree-vector%2Fprofile-avatar&psig=AOvVaw2GefCTODTxsxVvzrV4lp5z&ust=1674463308057000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBAQjRxqFwoTCKCf94fk2vwCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE", scale: 1)

answer for this========

Answer (score 0):

That link does not point to an image, but to a Google redirection page which points to an image-search page. You must provide a single image URL to the NetworkImage instance.